# Schema Namespace conflict

Tags: namespaces, xsd, schema, websphere

I have 2 schemas, namely
Request.xsd and Response.xsd
I have defined the target namespace to be the same in both xsd's. The problem is, when I deploy to WAS, I get schema namespace conflict error. I googled to check the solution. But I did not find anything concrete. 
I don't want to have two different target namespaces. Is there a way to overcome this error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about IBM WebSphere, right?

Comment: Yes Adriano. You are right

Comment: It doesn't really help but did you read [this](http://www.goland.org/wsdl11mess/) and (especially) [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220355)?

Comment: The second link explains the cause. Probably I will look around for other alternatives. I just checked with Tomcat, I do not see this issue. Thank you Adriano for highlighting this!

Comment: What is the reason `to have the schemas separate`?

Comment: @ Petru Gardea- Nothing logical. That was a requirement that we were asked to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a single XSD with 2 complex element 1 for request and other for reply

Comment: Not possible. It is a requirement to have the schemas separate